# How to inject OR condition in Entity Framework linq query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two and more if conditions to inject my main query but if the condition has no value (is nullable) I don't want to inject to my query.

For example this is my AND query injection:

```
// first initialize query can have where or not
var query = context.QuestionInfoes.Include(x =>x.RelationsInfoes).AsQueryable();

// first if condition to inject query
if (filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId.HasValue)
{
    query = (from q in query 
             join qr in context.QuestionRelationsInfoes on q.Id equals qr.QuestionId 
             where q.BrodcastType == QuestionBrodcastType.All || filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId == qr.ToProfileId 
             select q);
}

// second if condition to inject AND query and i want to this be OR injection
if (filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId.HasValue)
{
    query = (from q in query 
             where q.ProfileId == filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId 
             select q);
}
```

Now I want to create "OR" injection and when I call `.ToList()`, I see just queries in SQL that I needed. In top example if `ToProfileId` and `ProfileId` have values, I see questions where sent to `ToProfileId` value and 0 questions from profile id in "ProfileId" value because second query is "And" condition to first query. But I want both of them when I fill both values.

1. when two values are null: I filtered all of questions (works now)
2. when one value of ToProfileId or ProfileId is null: I filtered all of questions on that value is not null (works now)
3. When both value are filled, I want both question list (does not work now)

Note: I don't want to create one query and inject all of my condition in to that query.

Comment: Second query instead of "=" you want query.Add(........).  You may want to filter afterwards to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: ty for replay, what is query.Add ?

Comment: If you make first query (from .....).ToList() then you can add 2nd.

Comment: You can use IQueryable.Union, IQueryable.Concat for UNION/UNION ALL queries, or use the PredicateBuilder with predicate.Or. I don't know of any other possibilities once you actually have the IQueryable of the first condition. jdweng's solution is the same as the .Concat approach, will however fire multiple queries (depending on where you actually execute the IQueryable either all wrapped in one transactions or split over multiple transactions/connections)

Comment: I test concat or union not work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `QuestionRelationsInfoes` exists on `QuestionInfoes` as a navigation property called `QuestionRelationsInfoes`, then you dont need the `join`.

Unfortunately, you will have to construct the query based on the 3 scenarios (Both filters set, only 1st filter set, only 2nd filter set).

```
var query = context.QuestionInfoes.Include(x => x.RelationsInfoes);

if (filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId.HasValue && filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(q =>
        q.BrodcastType == QuestionBrodcastType.All ||
        q.QuestionRelationsInfoes.ToProfileId == filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId ||
        q.ProfileId == filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId);
}
else if (filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.BrodcastType == QuestionBrodcastType.All || filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId == q.QuestionRelationsInfoes.ToProfileId);
}
else if (filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(q.ProfileId == filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId);
}
```

As an alternative, if you dislike the code repetition, you can push the check to SQL, by first checking if the filter is not null:

```
var query = context.QuestionInfoes.Include(x => x.RelationsInfoes);

if (filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId.HasValue || filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(q =>
        (filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId.HasValue && (q.BrodcastType == QuestionBrodcastType.All || filterQuestionInfo.ToProfileId == q.QuestionRelationsInfoes.ToProfileId)) ||
        (filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId.HasValue && q.ProfileId == filterQuestionInfo.ProfileId));
}
```

Comment: ty for replay, In your code we dont have "Or" code injection,we separate all queries to one query with if and else if.your code works but I'm finding or code injection to make my work easy and remove duplicate code

Comment: You could also try manually creating an Expression<>, based on the properties set in filterQuestionInfo, but I cant offer a quick example on that.